# Regarding taking Xpath

Tags: xpath

Kindly follow the below HTML code. I want to get the text "DefaultBP" in between the  tag. If I using this XPath "`//div[@class='workspace']//h1`", all the texts including  tag such as "Export", "Import", "Tariff List" & "Add Prefix" are displayed. I want only the text "DefaultBP". Hope to hear from you soon.

```
    <div class="container-fluid">

    <input  type="hidden"  name="addressRuleId"  id="addressRuleId" value="1"/>
            <div class="row text-center">
                    <h1>DefaultBP
                    <a href="#" id="exportlink">Export</a>
                    <input type="hidden" id="status" name="status" value="null">
                    <input type="hidden" id="bpCode" name="bpCode" value="defaultbp">
                    <input type="hidden" id="bpName" name="bpName" value="DefaultBP">
                    <input type="hidden" id="addressRuleId" name="addressRuleId" value="1">
                    <a href="#" id="importbasebtn">Import</a> 
                    <!--<a href="/tariffs/import?bpName=DefaultBP">import</a>  -->                   
                     <a id="addprefixbtn" href="/tariffs/add-prefix?bpCode=defaultbp&bpName=DefaultBP&addressRuleId=1">Add Prefix</a>
                    <a href="/tariffs/show-tariffs">Tariff List</a></h1>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this Xpath

```
String text = driver.findElement(By.Xpath("//div[@class='row text-center']/following::h1"));
System.Out.Println(text.getText());
```

Comment: getText() is not a function of xpath. Moreover in your xpath you use the text you want to fetch. If you have the text to put to xpath expression why do you need to query exactly the same text..

Comment: @AlexeyR. Updated the answer. Please check.

Answer (score 0):

Given a path PPP that selects the `h1` element (for example `//div[@class='workspace']//h1`, though you haven't shown a `workspace` div in your input sample), you want

```
PPP/text()[1]
```

If you have an XPath API that's capable of returning strings rather than nodes, you could use

```
normalize-space(PPP/text()[1])
```

to get rid of the trailing whitespace.

`XXX/text()` selects all the child text nodes of an element, that is, the pieces of text that aren't wrapped in further nested elements. In this case you only want the first one, hence `[1]`.

Answer (score -1):

**String Default** = `driver.findElement(By.Xpath("//a[id='addprefixbtn']")).getText();`

Try this one